# clear both with float right does not extend to the end

Tags: css

I have the following [example](http://jsbin.com/eVUMENi/4/) where I am trying to create tabs, but for some reason the blue background does not extend to the end even with a `clear: both;`. It behaves the same whether I have `float: right;` or `float: left;`. Can somebody help me with this ?

Comment: Please try to explain the problem a little better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `width` to `100%` of the `ul` (`li` container), if you want the blue background to span across the entire screen.

```
ul {  
  background: #006daa;
  clear: both;
  float: right;
  width: 100%; /* changed */
}
```

http://jsbin.com/iVEwOxo/2

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the default padding on the `ul`.

In most browsers, a `ul` has a `padding-left` of `40px` to allocate spacing for the bullet points.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/34hdT/) - removing the padding

```
ul {
    background: #006daa;
    float: right;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Also, remove `clear:both`, as that doesn't have any effect in this instance.

**Results:**

> [image] ... **to**... 
>   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
overflow:auto;
```

on the container: http://jsbin.com/UfIYOWaD/1/edit

It happens because a non-floating element can't tell the size of a floating child unless forced to.

Comment: I am sorry, but what does `overflow` have to do with this problem? The reason your example works, is because the `ul` `width` is set to inherit it's parent's `width`, and `div` has a `width:100%` by default. Furthermore, `overflow` allows it to work, because `div` does not have a `height` set.

Comment: Also, it is not nice to downvote people, just because they downvote you for being wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/users/1194694/mike86?tab=reputation

Comment: Interestingly enough `overflow: auto;` does seem to do something. Check this out. http://jsbin.com/eVUMENi/5/edit Unfortunately it doesn't translate well into what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

How far are you trying to go? Do you literally want it to go all the way to the end?

First of all, set width: 100% on the ul:

```
ul {
   background: #006daa;
   clear: both;
   float: right;
   width: 100%;
}
```

That will extend the ul to the end of the page. If you don't want it to go all the way to the end of the page, either add padding to container:

```
.container {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Or wrap the ul with a different tag, like so:

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="main-navigation">
    <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
      <li>Third</li>
      <li>Fourth</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

And then add padding to that:

```
.main-navigation {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

It all depends on how far you want it to go, but usually setting width: 100% and defining the dimensions on a parent tag is the best way to make a bar like that when using floats.

Also, you should include code examples IN YOUR QUESTION. Linking to an external source is fine, but you should also include them in your question, too.